# Convert var type to GUID type

Tags: asp.net, guid

I have a var and want to change it to `System.GUID` .What should I do?

```
 var requstid =  Session ["y"];
```

want to convert type `var` to `GUID`.

Answer (score 0):

If Session contains `Guid`, then just cast to it:

```
var requstid = Session ["y"] != null ? (Guid)Session ["y"] : default(Guid);
```

Comment: Be careful with this as you could end up with runtime errors. At the very least, I'd make sure that "y" isn't null first before you cast it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var requestId = Guid.Parse(Session["y"]);
```

or

```
var requestId = new Guid(Session["y"]);
```